# How to fix bootstrapValidator error in php file

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't work with bootstrapValidation()

I have made a php file and included all the cdn of bootstrap 4.0 in that and then I have a made separate javaScript file and there i have made a bootstrapValidtor function to check input length and it's emptiness using jQuery and Ajax but it says **Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrapValidator is not defined at :1:1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <!-- included the CSS CDN of bootstrap 4.0.0-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

   <!-- online icons from fontawesome -->
   <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" >

</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 50%; margin: 20px auto">
  <form class="form needs-validation" action="" method="POST" id="contact-form" novalidate>

    <div class="input-group mb-3 size">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your First Name</div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group mb-3 size">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your Last Name</div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary text-align-center btn-block"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>

  </form>
</div>



<!-- This script is in external .js file -->
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
  //alert("HEllo Nehal");
  $("#contact-form").bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
      // valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      // invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      // validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
      first_name: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 10,
            message: "First Name should be at least 10 characters long"
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: "Please Enter Your First Name"
          }
        }
      },
      last_name: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 10,
            message: "Last Name should be at least 10 character long"
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: "please Enter your Last Name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
});

</script>

//external js file till here    

<!-- for bootstrap validation -->
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/PascaleBeier/bootstrap-validate/v2.2.0/dist/bootstrap-validate.js" ></script>

    <!-- online javaScript CDN of bootstrap 4.0.0 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not place the js files in the right order? i am sure bootstrap-validate should come AFTER bootstrap and jquery. also check the browser console for errors. make sure it´s loaded correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this solution.

```
<head>
    <!-- included the CSS CDN of bootstrap 4.0.0-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- online icons from fontawesome -->
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <!-- jQuery and Bootstrap JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- BootstrapValidator JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
    <!-- online javaScript CDN of bootstrap 4.0.0 -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

    <body>
    <div style="width: 50%; margin: 20px auto">

<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="contact-form"
data-bv-feedbackicons-valid="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
data-bv-feedbackicons-invalid="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
data-bv-feedbackicons-validating="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh">
<div class="input-group mb-3 size">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" required
data-bv-notempty="true"
data-bv-notempty-message="The username is required and cannot be empty">
<div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your First Name</div>
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3 size">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
</div>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" required
data-bv-notempty="true"
data-bv-notempty-message="The username is required and cannot be empty">
<div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your Last Name</div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary text-align-center btn-block"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i> Send</button>

</form>
</div>
    </body>

    <!-- This script is in external .js file -->
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
  //alert("HEllo Nehal");
  $('#registrationForm').bootstrapValidator();
});

</script>
```